# Kendo Grid, Uncaught ReferenceError: after cell button click

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, onclick, kendo-grid

i have this custom teplate in grid cell:

```
  template: (function (data){
            console.log(data.milestoneSequence);
            if(data.milestoneSequence == null || data.milestoneSequence == undefined) 
                {
                    this.cellBgColor = "red";
                    var customColum = 
                    "<div>"
                    + $translate.instant('MILESTONE_SEQUENCE_IS_NOT_ATTACHED')+ 
                    "<button onclick=\"attachSequence("+data.id+");\">"+$translate.instant('ATTACH')+
                    "</button></div>";
                    return customColum;
                }
             else {
                    var cellTemplate = data.milestoneSequence.name 
                    return cellTemplate;
             }
          }),
```

Problem is that after click on button i always got exception:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: attachSequence is not defined
```

Function is defined in controller, so i dont know how to execute function after button click.

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: IMO you should refactor your implementation. You have too much going on in that template function. However, did you try using `data-bind="click: attachSequence()"` instead of `onclick="attachSequence()"`?

Comment: I tried:
<button data-bind="click:findSequences(3);">ATTACH</button> but it is not working. In this case i did not receive error message : Uncaught ReferenceError: attachSequence is not defined.